# How to insert NULL for missing values in SQLAlchemy core?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The error I get is :
`sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'geboorteDatum' [SQL: 'INSERT into klanten (naam, geboorteDatum)VALUES(?, ?)'] [parameters: [{'naam': 'a'}]] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/cd3x)`

It comes from the statement: `connection.execute(text(sql), **kwargs)`, with `sql` being:

```
sql = ("INSERT into klanten "
       "(naam, geboorteDatum)"
       "VALUES(:naam, :geboorteDatum)")
```

The problem is that `kwargs` is missing a key-value pair (in this case for the key: 'geboorteDatum').

Is there a way to automatically use `NULL` in case of a missing key-value pair. It seems that this is possible when you use the ORM. But I don't use the ORM.

Attempts: I tried to convert the dict to a `collection.defaultdict` using `tmp = (collections.defaultdict(lambda : 'NULL', klant_info))`. This conversion works, however I get the same error. This is due the way that SQLAlchemy handles the dictionary. As can be seen in the method `_execute_clauseelement` found [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/6a622c636ca5bc55d96b92652fd43b914a77645c/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py), SQLAlchemy extracts all the keys, therefore using collection.defaultdict does not work.

Kind regards,

Comment: A `defaultdict` cannot create keys out of nothing when doing `**` argument unpacking, because that just unpacks what is already there in the dict.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

You can use `kwargs.get('geboorteDatum', None)`

OR

You can check the key geboorteDatum of **kwargs befor the insert and assert it in a variable like:

```
geboorteDatum = if 'geboorteDatum' in kwargs else None
```

and then use your variable in the insert statement.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm looking for a solution that works for all values. I don't want to code for every missing key.

Comment: That's kind of difficult you asking. You cannot set a default value for a key you probably know. You could set a default one if you knew the missing key name but I don't see other solution than that. Maybe you could parse your sql query read your values() names and create the missing keys with None values.

Comment: I would partially disagree, see my edit where I explain using collections.defaultdict (which is ofcourse not the same as a dict). I think I resolve this problem on the client side. Thanks for you efforts!

Answer (score 0):

If modifying `kwargs` is possible, then you could run

```
kwargs.setdefault('geboorteDatum')
```

before executing the statement. It will be a no-operation, if the key is in `kwargs`, and add `None` under it if not.

Comment: Is there a way to do that for all missing keys (not one at a time)? Because this key was only an example.

Comment: Depends. Usually you'd know what keys you're using, so it'd be a simple matter of looping over and calling `setdefault`. If you don't, but you have the `Table` at hand, you can inspect its columns and loop over their keys – but you're using text here.